# Disable button using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the following function to disable a button when there are not one or more tags in the text:

```
$scope.btnSendAll = function() {
    const description = $('#email_campaign_description');
    const tags = ('[nome]',
      '[consumer_current_points]',
      '[desconto]',
      '[vendor_name]',
      '[vendor_min_points]',
      '[consumer_registration_link]',
      '[min_purchase_for_discount]',
      '[max_discount_percentage]',
      '[transaction_points]',
      '[vendedor]');
    return !description.val().match(tags);
  }
```

The tags are inserted into a textarea and are sent when you click the button:

```
<button class="send to_all" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmation_modal" ng-disabled="btnSendAll()"> Enviar para todos <%= image_tag 'ajax_loader.gif', 'class': 'sending hide' %> </button>
```

The problem is that this function only works when you click outside the text field, so it checks whether or not there are tags and disables my button in case of negative, however if I keep my cursor in the text field and not click outside it, my function is not performed.

Can someone help me to leave this function in real time, whenever I type anything my function check for tags without having to click outside my text field.

Comment: Are you sure the function is not executed? It could also be that `description.val()` still contains the old value. That is why normally, you use ng-model to get the value of the textfield

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the function is not executed? It could also be that `description.val()` still contains the old value. That is why normally, you use `ng-model` to get the value of the textfield. Specifically even, with [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

```js
function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.btnSendAllEnabled = false;
  $scope.textAreaValue = "";
  $scope.btnSendAll = function() {
    const tags = [
      '[nome]',
      '[consumer_current_points]',
      '[desconto]',
      '[vendor_name]',
      '[vendor_min_points]',
      '[consumer_registration_link]',
      '[min_purchase_for_discount]',
      '[max_discount_percentage]',
      '[transaction_points]',
      '[vendedor]'
    ];
    $scope.btnSendAllEnabled = tags.some(function(t) {
      console.log(t, $scope.textAreaValue, $scope.textAreaValue.includes(t));
      return $scope.textAreaValue.includes(t);
    });
  }
}

angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", ctrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button class="send to_all" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmation_modal" ng-disabled="!btnSendAllEnabled">
    Enviar para todos
  </button>
  <textarea id="email_campaign_description" ng-model="textAreaValue" ng-change="btnSendAll()">
  </textarea>
</div>
```